# google compute engine - multiple static addresses pointing to one instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

In Compute engine 
Can you have 2 different ip addresses point to the same instance on different ports?

Static ip address-01 >> instance-01:80
Static ip address-02 >> instance-01:8080

Thanks

Comment: You can install and configure `iptables` per http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html on your GCE instance (assuming a Linux kernel) to do what you wish -- nothing GCE-specific about that; the one GCE extra you might add (though you could do that in `iptables` too) might be a firewall to just disallow ports outside the range you want.  To discuss iptables I recommend the serverfault site (and you can add a google-compute-engine tag to your Q there -- we're monitoring that now and will chime in if anything GCE-specific emerges).

Comment: In addition to what @AlexMartelli said, if you really need two static IPs you can create an instance with a static IP and create a load balancer also with a static IP directing traffic to that instance. In this way you'll have two static IPs pointing to the same machine. Then, you can use iptables on your instance to allow only ports 80 and 8080.